# Powershell: strange array / hashtable copyTo behaviour

Tags: powershell

I try to enumerate installed software on computers. I do this mostly on remote system using some keys in the registry. The function I have written works fine on some machines on others it does not. The problem seems to be to copy the array from a hashtable to an array of type PSCustomObject.
To avoid double entries (querying 32bit and 64bit hives in the registry) I have generated a hashtable with a key that is composed from the software name and version. Then I check if the key already exists before adding the data to the hashtable. At the end of the processing I copy the values of the hashtable to a pre-allocated array. Here is the code:

```
Function Get-InstalledSoftware
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$ComputerName
)

$RegistryLocation = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\',
'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\'
$htSoftware = @{ }

$RegBase = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $ComputerName)
foreach ($CurrentReg in $RegistryLocation)
{
    if ($RegBase)
    {
        $CurrentRegKey = $RegBase.OpenSubKey($CurrentReg)
        if ($CurrentRegKey)
        {
            foreach ($key in $CurrentRegKey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                $newreglocation = $CurrentReg + $key + '\'
                $cv = $RegBase.OpenSubKey($newreglocation)

                if ($cv.GetValue('DisplayName') -ne $null)
                {
                    $software = [PSCustomObject]@{
                        'Name' = $cv.GetValue('DisplayName')
                        'Version' = $cv.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                        'Publisher' = $cv.GetValue('Publisher')
                        'Installationsort' = $cv.GetValue('InstallLocation')
                        'Installationsdatum' = $cv.GetValue('InstallDate')
                    }
                }
                #$arrSoftware += $software
                $hashkey = $cv.GetValue('DisplayName') + "_" + $cv.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                if (!$htSoftware.ContainsKey($hashkey))
                {
                    $htSoftware.Add($hashkey, $software)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

[PSCustomObject[]]$arrSoftware = (1..$htSoftware.Count)
$htSoftware.Values.CopyTo($arrSoftware, 0)
$arrSoftware
}
```

The returned array is then filled into a gridview using some helper-functions like this:

```
    $form_computer_details.UseWaitCursor = $true
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
    $soft = Get-InstalledSoftware -ComputerName $ComputerName
    if ($soft -ne $null)
    {
        $table = ConvertTo-DataTable -InputObject $soft
        Load-DataGridView -DataGridView $datagridview_sw -Item $table
    }
    else
    {
        $richtextbox_ComputerInfoMsg.Text = "Konnte keine Daten aus der Registry des Computers $ComputerName lesen."    
    }
    $form_computer_details.UseWaitCursor = $false
```

After longer debugging sessions it seems the problem is with these two lines of code in my function:

```
    [PSCustomObject[]]$arrSoftware = (1..$htSoftware.Count)
$htSoftware.Values.CopyTo($arrSoftware, 0)
```

On machines where it is working the debugger shows the following content of the variable $arrSoftware after declaration and initialisation:

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"
```

After the CopyTo command the array looks as such:

```
$arrSoftware    "@{Name=Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) - ENU; Version=10.0.40219; Publisher=Microsoft Corporation; Installationsort=; Installationsdatum=20151128}", "@{Name=Microsoft SQL Server 2014 RsFx Driver; Version=12.0.2000.8; Publisher=Microsoft Corporation; Installationsort=; Installationsdatum=20151128}", .....
```

(I truncated the output.....)

On machines, where it is **NOT** working it looks as follows:

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"
```

ok so far, but now after copying:

```
(Empty)
```

But `$arrSoftware.count` shows the following result in the debugger:

```
$arrSoftware.count  22
```

When I look at the **first element** of the array I see the following:

```
$arrSoftware[0] @{Name=7-Zip 9.20 (x64 edition); Version=9.20.00.0; Publisher=Igor Pavlov; Installationsort=; Installationsdatum=20130526}
$arrSoftware[1] @{Name=Altaro Backup FS; Version=2.0.26.0; Publisher=Altaro; Installationsort=; Installationsdatum=20131221}
....
$arrSoftware[20]    @{Name=Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030; Version=11.0.61030; Publisher=Microsoft Corporation; Installationsort=; Installationsdatum=20151219}
```

Interestingly the last element for a size of 22 should be [21] which is EMPTY!

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: What's the motivation for initializing the array and copying the values to it with `CopyTo()` in the first place? `$arrSoftware = $htSoftware.Values|% { $_ }` would have the same effect

Comment: Well C# habits and .NET documentation... Tried your version but it does not change anything. Same behaviour.